# Google Api key invalid in pushwoosh

Tags: android, pushwoosh

Am developing html5 based mobile app using IONIC framework. When I send the push notification am getting an error of api key invalid, I have created my api key using my local ip address (192.168.1.75) in google developer console. Is am missing any thing. Is this is the way to create the api key.

This is the  error message am getting after sending push notification in pushwoosh

[image: This is the error message am getting in pushwoosh]

> Below image is how I have created the api key in google console.

[image]

Comment: You're going to need to put more effort into this question. Explain clearly what you have tried, show some code. As it stands, you are unlikely to get anyone invested in trying to help you.

Comment: @JamesWorld have added some more info.. please can you help me to figure it out..

Comment: sorry I'm not the expert here. But as far as I can tell, you haven't explained and shown what you have done in sufficient detail. How can someone check what you've done if you don't? Also, I doubt it's necessary or wise to advertise your API key. The problem could be in any of your code or configuration. So show/explain all of the relevant elements.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same behavior but now is working.

Try this:  On your Google Console - Server Key - Click on "Edit Allowed IPs" and remove your local ip address, left blank.

Back to PushWoosh panel > application > configuration > android - and replace the key with the Google Server Key.

I hope this help.